# Gremlin: What if my query cannot start with V() or E()?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, gremlinjs

The first query executed on my project runs on a potentially empty database, and creates some vertices if they are not created already, so my query cannot start with `V()` or `E()` because the database could be empty, also cannot start with `addE()` because first I need to check if the edge is not created, I've found the following solution using `inject()` but it looks like a hack:

```
g.inject("").union(
    coalesce(V().has("question", "questionId", 0), addV("question").property("questionId", 0)),
    coalesce(V().has("question", "questionId", 1), addV("question").property("questionId", 1)),
    coalesce(V().has("question", "questionId", 2), addV("question").property("questionId", 2))
)
```

Is there a way to write this in an elegant way without anything that looks hacky?

Comment: maybe I've just been doing Gremlin too long but `g.inject(0)` doesn't feel like a hack to me. when i think that something has to be in the traversal stream for there to be a stream  in the first place there is something about injecting a throwaway value that makes sense to me. while i believe that you have an answer to this below that uses `V()`, what other syntax might be better in cases where you couldn't?

Comment: I agree my solution feels less than a hack compared to the one in the answer. I consider something a hack when you use a tool made for a totally different purpose in order to workaround an issue. The purpose of inject is to add data into the traversal and not to workaround a query that does not start otherwise. I think gremlin should implement something like ```g.startEmptyTraversal()``` something made specifically for this need, otherwise it feels like a hack.

Comment: just to be clear `inject(0)` doesn't really bother me, nor does the answer from bechbd, but you're not the first person to not like `inject(0)` so i thought it was worth discussing a bit to see if you had any thoughts. i think an explicit `startEmpty()` breaks expected traversal semantics a bit too much. i do wonder however if steps like `union()` or `coalesce()` could be start steps, then `g.coalesce(V().has('name','alice'), addV().property('name','alice'))` or the like would be possible. not sure what the implications are but i'll make a note to think it through further. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario can be handled using an upsert pattern via the `fold()/unfold()` pattern described [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence).  This would look like the code below:

```
g.V().
  has("question", "questionId", 0).
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(), addV("question").property("questionId", 0)).
  V().
  has("question", "questionId", 1).
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(), addV("question").property("questionId", 1)).
  V().
  has("question", "questionId", 2).
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(), addV("question").property("questionId", 2))
```

Comment: Probably there is no alternative but this also looks like a hack to me because you need to execute fold() and unfold(), you are adding extra computation and using something made for a totally different purpose just because if you don't add this you cannot write the query

Comment: IMO the `fold().coalesce(unfold(),...)` pattern is more "Gremlin-ic" (akin to python being "pythonic") in that the query pattern is actually performing a graph traversal to perform a conditional write in a more imperative style.  Where as `inject(0)` or (if it were supported) starting with `coalesce()` directly would be attempting to write this query in a more declarative style.  Using `fold()`/`unfold()` may not add extra computation either.  Each TinkerPop graph database will parse, optimize, and execute these queries differently.  Many will optimize this pattern as it is very well known.